# run java maven project with command line

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I create a *HelloWorld* REST Web-Server with eclipse. I created a Dynamic Web Project with Eclipse, I converted the project to a maven project ... When I run the project with eclipse everything is working fine. Know I want to run the project with command line. I installed maven and then I run `mvn clean install site`.It build successfully. What shall I do after that ?

Comment: May be deploy your web project?

Comment: Where ? How ? which files was generated ? the build folder in empty... It's my first web application so I am a little bit confused...

Comment: Well, I realy don't know, but take a look at your target directory if therre is something like "war". Install tomcat, create new server in eclipse, add your project and deploy. Or copy your war file in the server webapps directory, will deploy. Start the server and go to the url (something like localhost:8080)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should deploy your created war on a server so that you can start using this. Within maven this can be done with the `cargo-maven2-plugin`.

An example of such a deployment with cargo is shown below:

```
            <!--
        Plugin to initiate instance of tomcat server
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <wait>true</wait>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>
                            http://apache.mirror1.spango.com/tomcat/tomcat-7/v${tomcat.version}/bin/apache-tomcat-${tomcat.version}.zip
                        </url>
                        <downloadDir>
                            ${project.build.directory}/downloads
                        </downloadDir>
                        <extractDir>
                            ${project.build.directory}/extracts
                        </extractDir>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                    <type>installed</type>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.jta</groupId>
                            <artifactId>narayana-jta</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.uniknow.tomcat</groupId>
                            <artifactId>narayana-tomcat-listener
                            </artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <!--<log>${project.build.directory}/logs/tomcat.log</log>-->
                    <!--<output>${project.build.directory}/logs/tomcat.out-->
                    <!--</output>-->
                </container>

                <!-- Configuration web server -->
                <configuration>
                    <type>standalone</type>
                    <home>${project.build.directory}/tomcat</home>
                    <properties>
                        <!--<cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>-->
                        <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                        <cargo.rmi.port>8206</cargo.rmi.port>
                        <cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>8010</cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>
                    </properties>
                    <files>
                        <copy>
                            <file>${basedir}/src/config/server.xml</file>
                            <todir>conf</todir>
                            <configfile>true</configfile>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        </copy>
                        <copy>
                            <file>${basedir}/src/config/context.xml</file>
                            <todir>conf</todir>
                            <configfile>true</configfile>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        </copy>
                    </files>
                </configuration>

                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This is part of the project you can find here [tutorials/rest](https://github.com/UniKnow/AgileDev/tree/develop/tutorials/rest)